# excel vba search cell

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible for excel to search strings and compare it against another array of strings on another columns

For example,

> I have a series of users in A1. I want to search and check all users
>   in cell A1 against "list of names" in Column C.

[image]

I would like to see results something that look like this. Possible?

[image]

Regards,
Terry

Comment: Yes definitely possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come out with my own answers and it worked though its a bit lengthy.

```html
Sub search()
    Dim users As Variant
    Dim search As Boolean
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim found As Integer
    Dim ArraySize As Integer
    Dim listSize As Integer
    Dim listOfUsers As Integer
    
    listSize = 2
    
    search = False
    
    'Count number of teachers in List Of Users column
    listOfUsers = Range("C2:C1000").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    
    While Cells(listSize, 1).Value <> ""
        found = 0
        users = Split(Cells(listSize, 1).Value, ",")
        ArraySize = UBound(users, 1) ' Find array size
        
        'Loop until each cell string is done
        For i = 0 To ArraySize
            j = 2
            While search = False
                If Trim(users(i)) = Cells(j, 3).Value Then
                    Cells(listSize, 2).Value = Trim(users(i))
                    found = found + 1
                    search = True
                ElseIf j > listOfUsers Then
                    search = True
                Else
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            Wend
            search = False
        Next i
        If found <> ArraySize + 1 Then
        Cells(listSize, 2).Value = "Users not found"
        Else
        Cells(listSize, 2).Value = "All users found"
        End If
        listSize = listSize + 1
    Wend
    
End Sub
```

Regards,
Terry

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Dictionary` object

```
Option Explicit

Sub search()
    Dim usersRng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim elem As Variant
    Dim SearchResults As String
    Dim searchResultsArray As Variant
    Dim iCell As Long

    Set usersRng = Range("A2", Cells(Rows.COUNT, "A").End(xlUp)) '<-- set usersRng in column "A" from row 2 down to last not empty row
    ReDim searchResultsArray(1 To usersRng.COUNT) '<--| size the search result array to the actual number of cells to be processed

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'create and reference a 'dictionary'
        'store all values from "list of users" column in reference dictionary
        For Each cell In Range("C2", Cells(Rows.COUNT, "C").End(xlUp))
            .Add cell.Value, Null
        Next cell

        For Each cell In usersRng '<--| loop through "users" column cells
            SearchResults = "" '<--| initialize search results
            For Each elem In Split(Replace(cell.Value, " ", ""), ",") '<--| loop through current cell users
                If Not .Exists(elem) Then SearchResults = SearchResults & elem & "," '<--| if current user is not in the dictionary then update 'searchResults' string
            Next elem
            If SearchResults = "" Then '<--| if all users have been found...
                SearchResults = "All users found" '<--| ... then set 'searchResults' accordingly
            Else '<--| otherwise...
                SearchResults = Left(SearchResults, Len(SearchResults) - 1) & " not found" '<--| ... add " not found" to the already built list of not found users
            End If
            iCell = iCell + 1 '<--| update 'searchResultsArray' index
            searchResultsArray(iCell) = SearchResults '<--| update 'searchResultsArray'
        Next cell
        Range("B2").Resize(usersRng.COUNT).Value = Application.Transpose(searchResultsArray) '<--| write down 'searchResultsArray' from cell "B2" downwards
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are welcome. Dictionaries allows for much faster code than looping through cells only. The same holds true for using arrays and then write them into cells. Finally, If my answer solved your question you may want to accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @xingtan, I see you keep asking and getting good answers but never mark them as accepted. As per this site rules (see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)) you have to _click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in_. Thank you!

Comment: @xingtan, in what your answer is better than mine?